# Angular - getting article by id

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I am new to both ionic and angular and can't get my article by id, I get the list of articles from api, and that works but getting an article by id is not working. This is my code:

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])

.controller('FrontPageController', function($scope, ArticleService) {
  ArticleService.all().then(function(data){
    $scope.articles = data;
  })
})

.controller('ArticleController', function($scope, ArticleService, $stateParams) {
  var article = ArticleService.get($stateParams.id);
});
```

Services:

```
.factory('ArticleService', function($http) {

  return {
    all: function() {
       return $http.get("http://myApp.app/api/articles/latest").then(function(response){
             articles = response.data;
             return articles;
          });
       },
    get: function(id) {
      var articles = this.all();

      for (var i in articles) {
        if (articles[i].id == id) {
          return articles[i];
        }
      }

      return {};
    }
  };
});
```

And list view:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="article in articles" href="#/main/article/{{article.id}}">
        <div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-avatar">
          <h3>{{ article.title }}</h3>
          <div ng-repeat="media in article.medias">
            <img src="http://myApp.app/{{media.path}}">
            <p>{{media.path}}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-body">
          <img class="full-image" src="http://myApp.app/{{media.path}}">
          <p>
            This is a "Facebook" styled Card. The header is created from a Thumbnail List item,
            the content is from a card-body consisting of an image and paragraph text. The footer
            consists of tabs, icons aligned left, within the card-footer.
          </p>
          <p>
            <a href="#" class="subdued">1 Like</a>
            <a href="#" class="subdued">{{ article.commentsCount }} Comments</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </ion-item>
```

This is what the list of objects look like when I do `console.log($scope.articles)` in `FrontPageController` (I have shown just for the first one what it looks like):

```
Object {1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object, 4: Object, 5: Object, 7: Object, 32: Object, 33: Object, 50: Object}
1
:
Object
```

Object contains the value like as follows :

```
category_id:1
commentsCount:3
created_at:"2016-05-10 13:56:45"
id:1
medias:Array[0]
slug:"-11"
summary:"dsvsdv"
text:"<p>sdvsdv</p>"
title:"sdvsdv"
type_id:1
updated_at:"2016-06-02 08:19:46"
user_id:3
__proto__
```

And when I do `console.log(article)` in `ArticleController` I get empty object. 
For `console.log(articles)` in `get: function` in `services` I get:

```
Promise {$$state: Object}
$$state
```

**Updated code**

This worked for me in the end, if anyone will need it in the future.

Services:

```
get: function(id) {
      return this.all().then(function(response) {
      var articles = response;
      for (var i in articles) {
        if (articles[i].id == id) {
          return articles[i];
        }
      }
      return {};
      })
    }
```

Controller:

```
.controller('ArticleController', function($scope, ArticleService, $stateParams) {
  ArticleService.get($stateParams.id).then(function(response) {
    $scope.article = response;
  })
});
```

Comment: please show the your json for article object

Comment: you got the error in controller or in view

Comment: I have updated my question with outputs for json objects. I get no errors.

Comment: please check your $stateParams.id value and check the articles value in  get: function(id) on console

Comment: I have updated again my question, and I get the id from console.log($stateParams.id); it outputs the correct id

Comment: please check the log in if condition

Comment: I get nothing there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the object is empty because you use asynchronous method. When you call the `this.all()` method, that send an HTTP request to an endpoint. This action takes time and during this time, `articles` are undefined so you don't enter the for loop.

Try this :

```
var articles = this.all().then(function(response) {
      var articles = response;
      angular.forEach(articles, function(article){
        if (article.id == id) {
          return article;
        }
      }
      return {};
})
```

According to AngularJS documentation, **then**  calls one of the success or error callbacks asynchronously as soon as the result is available. So articles will not be empty this time.

Comment: Now I am getting the object in get function, but in my controller I am getting undefined for var article = ArticleService.get($stateParams.id);
console.log(article);

Comment: well, in if loop I did console.log(articles[i]) and I got the correct object:  Object {id: 1, title: "sdvsdv", slug: "-11", category_id: 1}

Comment: It's the same issue : asynchronous method. Try this : ArticleService.get($stateParams.id).then(function(response) { var article = response; console.log(article);})

Comment: When I do that I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: I had to change get function in services, instead of var articles at the begging I put return and now I am getting the object! Thank you!

Comment: Ok, didn't understand everything but that's great ;)